# Let $p ≥ 3$ be a prime number, let $r ∈ N$, and let $x$ be a primitive root modulo $p^{r}$. Show that $x$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Tags: number-theory

I want to prove this: Let $p ≥ 3$ be a prime number, let $r ∈ N$, and let $x$ be a primitive root modulo $p^{r}$. Show that $x$ is a primitive root modulo $p$.

Well I don't have any ideas, I know that $gcd(x,p)=1$ and that's the beginning of the proof, but have no idea how to continue, i'm stuck and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Try homomorphism onto $Z_p$? I'm not sure if this will work, but seems like it might.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose to the contrary that $x$ is not a primitive root of $p$. Then there is an $a$, with $1\le a\le p-1$, such that $x^n\not\equiv a\pmod{p}$ for all positive integers $n$.

But then $x^n\not\equiv a\pmod{p^r}$ for all natural numbers $n$. It follows that $x$ is not a primitive root of $p^r$.This contradicts the given fact that $x$ is a primitive root of $p^r$.

Comment: why then $x^n\not\equiv a\pmod{p^r}$ ?

Comment: @CnR: If $x^n\equiv a\pmod{p^r}$, then automatically $x^n\equiv a\pmod{p}$. (If $p^r$ divides $x^n-a$, then $p$ divides $x^n-a$.)